# the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate

Tags: json, rust

In one of my structs `Struct1` there's a field of type `time::Tm`. Somewhere in the code an instance of the struct gets decoded from a json string to an instance of  `Struct1`.

`json::decode(&maybe_struct1)`

At first I got an error saying that `to_json isn't implemented for time::Tm`. So I implemented it:

```
impl json::ToJson for time::Tm {
  fn to_json(&self) -> json::Json {
    let mut d = BTreeMap::new();
    d.insert("tm_sec".to_string(), self.tm_sec.to_json());
    d.insert("tm_min".to_string(), self.tm_min.to_json());
    //..............
```

And now it says

```
error: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate; only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types  [E0117]
```

I gathered that it was a bug before version 1. But it is still? If not how do I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a bug - it is feature. Really. To implement trait any of this statements must be true:

- type is declared in this module
- trait is declared in this module

otherwise you get `E0117`. You can find more info using `rustc --explain E0117`:

> This error indicates a violation of one of Rust's orphan rules for trait implementations. The rule prohibits any implementation of a foreign trait (atrait defined in another crate) where
>
> - the type that is implementing the trait is foreign
> - all of the parameters being passed to the trait (if there are any) are also foreign.
>
> Here's one example of this error:
>
> ```
> impl Drop for u32 {}
> ```
>
> To avoid this kind of error, ensure that at least one local type is referencedby the `impl`:
>
> ```
> pub struct Foo; // you define your type in your crate
>
> impl Drop for Foo { // and you can implement the trait on it!
>     // code of trait implementation here
> }
>
> impl From<Foo> for i32 { // or you use a type from your crate as 
>     // a type parameter   
>     fn from(i: Foo) -> i32 { 0 }
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, define a trait locally and implement that instead:
>
> ```
> trait Bar {
>     fn get(&self) -> usize;
> }
> impl Bar for u32 {
>     fn get(&self) -> usize { 0 }
> }
> ```
>
> For information on the design of the orphan rules, see [RFC 1023](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1023).

### EDIT:

To achieve what you want you have 2 solutions:

- implement `ToJson` on your whole type:

  ```
   impl json::ToJson for Struct1 { … }
  ```
- create a wrapper type `struct TmWrapper(time::Tm);` and implement 2 traits for it `From` and `ToJson`.

### EDIT 2:

Step by step explonation:

1. This is what you want to achieve: http://is.gd/6UF3jd
2. Solutions:

   - implement trait on whole type **using** types that you want: http://is.gd/CRfPeJ
   - create wrapper type and implement trait that you want on it: http://is.gd/7XV5w9

This is **exactly** what is described in explanation of the error code above.

So you see - at least one of trait or struct must be declare within current unit to allow implementation of trait on given type. In your case both of them are external types and that is what is Rust preventing. If you want to achieve something like that you need to use some hacks as described above.

Comment: but it's already a field of my struct `In one of my structs Struct1 there's a field of type time::Tm`

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to `impl` on that type, not on yours. Check my answer for solution.

Comment: here you are **At first I got an error saying that to_json isn't implemented for time::Tm** when I'd implemented **to_json** for my own type Struct1

Comment: If you tried to use `#[derive(…)]` or implicit any kind of implicit definition then it will fail. You need to implement **whole** `ToJson` for your own struct, no shortcuts, no autodefinitions, nothing - just you and your code. I gave you enough examples, but I'll try once more with Rust Playpen.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a bug.  The language requires when you implement a trait that *you* defined either the trait or the type involved.  If you implemented *neither*, it doesn't allow it.

If it didn't, it would be possible for someone else to come along and *also* implement `json::ToJson` for `time::Tm`, and suddenly the compiler has no idea which code to use.

The simplest way to work around this is to wrap your `time::Tm` in a newtype, like so:

```rust
struct TmWrap(time::Tm);
```

Now, because *you* defined this type, you can implement `json::ToJson` on it.  This does mean you have to wrap/unwrap the `Tm` constantly, but the only other alternative is to implement `ToJson` for the *entire* containing `Struct1` type, which is probably going to be even *more* work.

Comment: but it's already a field of my struct `In one of my structs Struct1 there's a field of type time::Tm`

Comment: You're trying to implement `ToJson` for an external type.  That you're using it as part of a locally-defined structure is irrelevant.  Either the type *itself* or the trait **have** to be locally-defined.

Comment: the type itself is defined locally. and since it has the field of type "time::Tm", in order to implement to_json for it, I have to break it down and  implement to_json for "time::Tm"

Comment: @jawanam: As I've already said, you have to *either* implement `ToJson` for `Struct1` **without** breaking it down (*i.e.* `Struct1` would *also* have to convert the `Tm` field to JSON itself), *or* you have to wrap the `Tm` in a local type.  The compiler *does not care* that you are using `Tm` in a field of a locally-defined structure.

Comment: The alterative design would be Javascript, with a prototype chain, allowing you to completely rewrite the language at runtime, as a workaround to obsolete browser runtimes.